# Trouble applying gram-schmidt to two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As the title suggest I'm trying to apply the gram-schmidt to two vectors $\{v_1, v_2\}$ in order to find the orthonormal basis $\{q_1, q_2\}$.

$$
V_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
4\\
2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And

$$
V_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
-3\\
4\\
3\\
4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
q_1 = \frac{1}{||v_1||}v_1 = \frac{1}{5} \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 4\\ 2\\\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{4}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
q_2 = v_2 - Proj_{v_1} v_2 = v_2 - \left(v_2\cdot q_1\right) q_1
$$

$$
 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 4\\ 2\\\end{pmatrix} - \left(\begin{pmatrix}-3\\ 4\\ 3\\ 4\\\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{4}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\\end{pmatrix}\right) \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{4}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 4\\ 2\\\end{pmatrix} - 5\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{4}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 4\\ 2\\\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 4\\ 2\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix} ... wrong! also q_2 / ||q_2|| normalize...
$$

If someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
$$
q_1 = \frac{1}{||v_1||}v_1 = \frac{1}{5} \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 4\\ 2\\\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{4}{5}\\ \frac{2
}{5}\\\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
q_2 = v_2 - Proj_{v_1} v_2 = v_2 - \left(v_2\cdot q_1\right) q_1
$$

$$
 = \begin{pmatrix}-3\\ 4\\ 3\\ 4\end{pmatrix} - \left(\begin{pmatrix}-3\\ 4\\ 3\\ 4\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{4}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\\end{pmatrix}\right) \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{4}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
 = \begin{pmatrix}-3\\ 4\\ 3\\ 4\end{pmatrix} - 5\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\ \frac{4}{5}\\ \frac{2}{5}\\\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}-3\\ 4\\ 3\\ 4\end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\\ 4\\ 2\end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ 2\\ -1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Does that look right? Also now I jsut have to divide $q_2$ by $||q_2||$, right? Which is 5 so

$$
q_2 = \begin{pmatrix}-4/5\\ 2/5\\ -1/5\\ 2/5\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: You write $q_2=v_2-\ldots$, but the next line has $v_1-\ldots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just made a silly mistake: you wrote $q_2=v_2-(v_2\cdot q_1)q_1$ but you accidentally substituted $v_1$ for the first $v_2$.